# How to make a non-thread-safe 3rd party library actually thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have a 3rd party library that offers a class.  Their documentation says:

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are safe for multithreaded operations. Instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

I did some testing where I created 100 threads.  Indeed there are thread safety issues if I pass the same object to all 100 threads, but those problems appear to go away if each thread creates its own instance of the class.

I'm using .NET 4.0 here.  In my application there are multiple threads that will want to use this class, but I don't want to create and destroy the objects more than necessary (they should live for the lifetime of the application), so I want one per thread.  Is this an appropriate use of the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28VS.100%29.aspx) class?  If not, what is the standard way to handle this?

**Edit**:

Some more information about the 3rd party class.  It's a communication library and opens a communication link to another process, either on this computer or another computer.  The other end of the communication link is designed to accept concurrent connections.  Therefore I shouldn't need to synchronize the method calls on my end by using `lock`s.  However, each instance is not thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the objects to interact with each other *at all*, `ThreadLocal<T>` is a very good choice here. It obviously doesn't work if modifications made in one thread are *meant* to be seen in another thread, just safely.

Yes, it will create one object per thread - but unless creating the objects is *really* expensive, you're likely to have on the order of hundreds of instances, which in most cases is absolutely fine.

One classic example of this is `System.Random`:

- You don't want to create instances on an ad hoc basis, as if you're not careful you'll end up with multiple instances with the same seed
- It's definitely *not* thread-safe.

So you could do something like:

```
public static class RandomProvider
{
    private static readonly Random seedProvider = new Random();

    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> threadLocal =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(InitializeNewRandom);

    public static Random GetRandomForThread()
    {
        return threadLocal.Value;
    }

    private static Random InitializeNewRandom()
    {
        lock(seedProvider)
        {
            return new Random(seedProvider.Next(int.MaxValue));
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to write a thread-safe proxy class which used locking for each operation - but that still has issues if you have multiple operations which you wish to execute "atomically" (i.e. without interleaving other calls).

Comment: The class is a communication client, and connects to a different process on the PC or another PC.  The other end can handle concurrent connections.  The individual instances in my application should *not* be interacting (at least not within my application).

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: Right. In that case, it really does sound like a good fit. You might want to introduce an intermediary (e.g. a `ClientProvider`) for the sake of testing, mind you...

Comment: Yes, it was already inside of a wrapper class, and I'm doing exactly that, creating a `ClientProvider` whose sole job is to return an instance of the client class.  That provider will use `ThreadLocal<T>`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that making a wrapper above this class which blocks all operations with Monitors( lock keyword) or other thread blocking sync construct can help.

But it does not guarantee absence of possible deadlocks and race conditions. Without complete rewrite of the original class and its consumers you may still run into a problem.

You can't make unsafe thing safe and unsecure thing secure in postprocessing. Such qualities must be considered at first and this is even not your library.